# The most trusted hard problem

Tags: encryption

Is there a mathematical formalism to rank the hardness of the hard problems?

In particular I am referring to the sort of hard problems that are typically used in cypher system; such as factorization for RSA or the number theoretic method used in AES.

Please note that by a rank system I am not referring the belief that one problem is harder than the other because it has been around longer, I am asking for some formalism.

Comment: This new question should be in crypto.SE

Comment: Do you mean space/time complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. And no.

One-time-pads are provably uncrackable because every solution is equally probable. They're also totally useless in all but a few cases.

RSA and AES are so different as to not really be comparable. RSA relies on the difficulty of certain computations, while AES doesn't use math in the traditional sense. It scrambles the bits very directly, so the best attack we have is a direct brute-force on the key itself. An "ideal" attack would involve finding a weakness in the *way* the bits were scrambled, such that you could find some statistical bias that could be exploited. But that's not math in the sense of factoring primes. You're not attacking the problem head on, you're looking for subtle mistakes.

Even DES, the first "strong" cipher we've ever had, is unbroken in the sense that the easiest attack is a brute-force one. It's just crippled by the fact that the key size makes brute-force relatively easy.

Finding a form of "unbreakable" symmetric encryption isn't really the problem.

Comment: I hope you decide to improve on this answer in the future. I up voted and accepted. Enjoy the points!